# React native(android) assembleRelease gets bundle assembling error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, react-native

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "load-script": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.4.0",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

//build.gradle android
    buildscript {
        ext {
            buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
            minSdkVersion = 16
            compileSdkVersion = 28
            targetSdkVersion = 28
            supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        }
    }
```

i ran **.\gradlew assembleRelease** and it crashed after that i ran the same command with **--info** and this is what it's showing me
i've tried upgrading and down grading and removing some of unused libs but nothing changed.

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Caching disabled for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
Starting process 'command 'cmd''. Working directory: C:\Users\MOBILE1\Desktop\Gitlab-Devloper-Branch\dev-branch\build-apk-error-last\mbz-mobile-app Command: cmd /c node node_modules/react-native/cli.js bundle --platform android --dev false --reset-cache --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output C:\Users\MOBILE1\Desktop\Gitlab-Devloper-Branch\dev-branch\build-apk-error-last\mbz-mobile-app\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle --assets-dest C:\Users\MOBILE1\Desktop\Gitlab-Devloper-Branch\dev-branch\build-apk-error-last\mbz-mobile-app\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release
Successfully started process 'command 'cmd''
warning: the transform cache was reset.
error The resource `C:\Users\MOBILE1\Desktop\Gitlab-Devloper-Branch\dev-branch\build-apk-error-last\mbz-mobile-app\index.android.js` was not found.. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 3.955 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
```

i also get **uses or overrides a deprecated API** and **Deprecated Gradle features were used, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0** for **react-native-gesture-handler** in android studio. i get

Answer (score 1):

Try this once ,  `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` please check once.

UPDATE:

`gradlew assembleRelease` will only build/bundle your application for production. You need to sign the APK file yourself.

These are the steps which I take when I want to run my application in production mode:

1.keytool -genkey -v -keystore key.keystore -alias app-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

2.`cd android && gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..`

3.`jarsigner -verbose -keystore \path_to_key\key.keystore \path_to_apk\app-release-unsigned.apk app-alias`

4.`zipalign -f -v 4 \path_to_apk\app-release-unsigned.apk appName.apk`

Follow these steps and your app should be installed successfully.

Do revert in case of any concerns.

Comment: it builds app-release-unsigned and it can't be installed

Answer (score 0):

Please use the same compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion and support library projects as in the main application project.